# Publishing packages to Azure DeveOps Artifacts using Python-Poetry

Tags: python, azure-devops, python-poetry

## The background

I've seen this answer, [How to Publish to PyPI with Azure-Pipelines and Poetry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55435392/how-to-publish-to-pypi-with-azure-pipelines-and-poetry) however, where the credentials are supposedly generated, I don't see that same option when I go to `Connect to Feed` > `Python`. All I see is `pip` and `twine`, both of which show how to do unauthenticated pushes.

I have an Azure DevOps Artifacts Python Feed setup where I am the administrator to it. I wanted to use `poetry` to publish or push the package I am working on into that Feed. However, when prompted for my credentials, I use my email, and password I use to login, but I don't think these are correct. I get a 401 Unauthorized. So here is the steps that I am doing

I created the project

```sh
poetry new phil_hello_world --src
```

I then added some boiler plate code in `src/phil_hello_world/__init__.py`

```py
__version__ = '0.1.0'


def hello_world():
"""Hello World Function
"""
print('Hello, World!')
```

Then I was able to build and install the package and use it in IDLE and some other scripts.

```sh
poetry build
```

## The problem

So, where this comes to the problem is getting my Azure DevOps Python Artifact Feed setup properly. They recommend using pip or twine, but I'm trying to use this, so bear with me.

First, I setup the repostiory so Poetry knows about it. We're going to do a local configuration.

```sh
poetry config repostiories.azure-python-feed https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myOrg/Project/_packaging/azure-python-feed/pypi/upload
```

Then I tried just pushing the package up using:

```sh
poetry publish -r azure-python-feed --build
```

I then got a 401 Unauthorized error.

So, I tried to use my login information by doing:

```sh
poetry config http-basic.azure-python-feed ${USER_EMAIL} ${USER_LOGIN_PASS}
```

buuuuut, I still get 401 Unauthorized. Am I doing something wrong? I did make sure to add the recommended packages listed in the Connect Me pop-out.

```sh
poetry add twine keyring artifacts-keyring
poetry install
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Publish to PyPI with Azure-Pipelines and Poetry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55435392/how-to-publish-to-pypi-with-azure-pipelines-and-poetry)

Comment: @Arne, not quite. I saw that first, but the step where they get the credentials doesn't exist or I don't see it in my Azure DevOps Artifacts section when I click on Connect to Feed. I only see `pip` or `twine` and then it shows to how setup an unauthenticated push.

Comment: Too bad, I don't have access to an azure devops environment so I can't actually debug the problem. The only thing I can add is that if you use poetry and set it up, you for sure don't need twine or pip.

Comment: This is true. You do not need twine or pip to upload packages. However, pip is probably already installed with your installation.

Comment: @FilBot3 did you figure out what you needed to do?

Comment: Yes I did. The accepted answer is what worked for me. There are still improvements being made in the Poetry repo, I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To narrow down the issue, you may try the following items:

1. Try to create a new PAT with `Full access`, and then try it again.
2. Try to run command `poetry publish -u $(username) -p $(password) ...`

The `$(username)` can be anything, except blank. Remember to also use the `-r` option to define your repository.

Comment: When you say `$(username)` is that blank like other times I've interacted with the Azure DevOps REST API, or is that the full email I use to login?

Comment: When you use PAT, the `username` is supposed to be anything.

Comment: You could probably also use the `$(System.AccessKey)` to push to the feed in Azure.